# HTML printing textbox values

Tags: php, html

I want users to fill out a signup like so:

```
<h1>Enlistment Form</h1>
<form name="input" action="http://spartancorps-gil.comyr.com/Enlistment.php" method="get">
<p>First Name?: </p> 
<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="" />
<p>Last Name?: </p>
<input type="text" name="lastname" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

It sends to a server with this php:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>
<?PHP
$Firstname = $_POST['FirstName'];
print ($Firstname);
$Lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
print ($Lastname);
</head>
</html>
```

For some reason it isn't printing out these values. What am I missing here?

Comment: please, show the form code

Comment: where is your php closing tag?Please change the form method to post method since you are using $_POST for getting the values in php

Comment: @ THE ONLY ONE actually I just realized that might be it. I haven't had much experience with html/php, sorry....

Comment: change method="get" to method="post", cause u get the value by post method $Firstname = $_POST['FirstName'];

Comment: @THEONLYONE apparently that didn't fix it, I don't think it's the issue

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `method="GET"` in your form and in second file you are using `$_POST` for getting that values:

Do like this: Use `method="POST"` in you form:

Example:

```
<form name="input" action="http://spartancorps-gil.comyr.com/Enlistment.php" method="POST">
```

and use do like this:

```
echo $_POST['FirstName'];

echo $_POST['LastName'];
```

Read about "superglobals" in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code to this and try...
Please change the method of form to post and close the php tag

```
<form name="input" action="http://spartancorps-gil.comyr.com/Enlistment.php" method="post">

<?PHP
$Firstname = $_POST['FirstName'];
print_r($Firstname);
$Lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
print_r($Lastname);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You submitting the form with `GET`, but trying to read `$_POST`. So either change method to `POST` in your form, or use `$_GET` to read submitted values.
2. Make sure that url in `action` points to correct php file.
3. Close php tag after `print ($Lastname);`

Answer (score 0):

try this one, just close your php tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>
<?PHP
$Firstname = $_POST['FirstName'];
echo $Firstname;
$Lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
echo $Lastname;
?>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: in your form change the method from get to post, like this method="post"

Answer (score -1):

You have to change "print" to "echo" like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>
<?PHP
$Firstname = $_POST['FirstName'];
echo $Firstname;
$Lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
echo $Lastname;
</head>
</html>
```